# Does a horn that calls for a 20A fuse draw too much current to be direct connected?

Tags: automotive

I'm repairing the horn on a 91 Ford Ranger. The old horn burned out and there are breaks in the wiring where I cannot access them. So I can run new wires without issue.
I removed the steering wheel and cleaned the contacts. The buttons now work again but the wires look to be 18awg.
I'm hesitant to let the upper limit of 20A @ 12V to pass through these thin wires.
Instead, I think a relay is the way to go. I've got a 40A @ 14V with a 12V coil relay on hand. Is it prudent to use the horn switch to trigger the relay and power the horn or am I being overly cautious?

Comment: You're not planning on honking for minutes on end are you? If you are, I recommend you also add a toggle switch while you're at it. It'll be more convenient.

Comment: @DKNguyen Not minutes but I have had to for about 20 or 30 seconds before to scare game off the road. Also not sure why the old one burned out, probably age, but I'd hate to recreate a bad position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1:**

Use automotive 18 AWG wire and downgrade the fuse to 15 Amp slow-blow fuse. I doubt the horn really needs 20 Amps. Example wire is SAE J1128 GXL wire. Rated to 125 C. This is not exotic or expensive wire (you can type "SAE J1128 GXL" into a search engine).

Automotive wire has a high insulation temperature, and the NEC ampacity table does not apply. It should be OK to protect automotive 18 AWG wire with a 15 Amp fuse.

**Option 2:**

Use 16 AWG automotive wire with a 20 Amp fuse.

I would not use a relay because it seems like too much trouble, and there was originally no relay.

Comment: That's an exceptionally informative answer, but the 18AWG is tied into the steering wheel pickups and cannot be changed there, nor is it easy to get new wire through the firewall and up the steering column. While the slow-blow 15A sounds like it will work, I'd prefer not to take the new AWOOGA horn out of spec as it cost more than a few dollars for a quality one. Thank you for the time to respond though.

Comment: The only danger with the slow-blow fuse is that it may blow when you AWOOGA. It won't "take the horn out of spec." If it blows then you know you need to use a 20 A fuse. I thought you had to rewire anyway. But now it sounds like some of the original wire is still intact. Personally, I feel you are doing too much work. The combination of a 20 A fuse with 18 AWG wire is not totally sound, but since it is the OEM wire size, it is probably OK. Afterall, the starter on the car has no fuse at all, and the starter wire is always undersized for the load (if you consider the continuous load).

Comment: Except for the issue, which is totally my fault for leaving out, that the original horn has a 15A fuse. Which is what lead me to be concerned to begin with as I rarely encounter over-engineering when I am repairing a vehicle. I'm trying to get better at asking these questions and providing all the information possible without being garrulous.

Comment: I see. So you are upgrading the horn, and your concern is that the 18 AWG wire may not be up to the task of driving the new horn. The old horn had a 15 amp fuse, and you believe the new horn may use up to 20 amps. Given all that, using a relay may very well be the best course of action. Please note that you still need a 15 amp  or smaller fuse in series with the 18 AWG wire that runs to the horn switch. You can't increase it to 20 amps if you want to keep the 18 AWG wire. You can add a separate 20 amp inline fuse to put in series with the horn.

Comment: Excellent, thanks again. Since the horn is in the engine compartment I am running a new 14 AWG hot from the battery to the NO on the relay, then onto the horn. I'm grounding the horn to the firewall ground with a new wire as well. The old line that goes through the firewall, the old fuse (by itself), through the horn switch and back out of the firewall, so that has the recommended fuse already. I'm tapping that to the new 14 from the battery. Then the fuse, horn, and two grounds (coil and horn) and I think I'm good to go. You rock for checking back and sticking with me through this.

Answer (score 3):

A horn relay is a good idea. Many cars these days (*cough* Toyota *cough*) use them by design, but it does not surprise me that Ford would cheap out here.

Comment: It just made sense to me that they would be done that way. Nice to know my hypothesis aligns with the current mode of thinking, and what's a 3 dollar relay in comparison to piece of mind? Thanks for confirming it for me.

Comment: Got it done, my truck now Awoogas.

Comment: Loud enough for elk? Moose? Well done.